# Keep an usually amount of data updated in all active users web application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm developing an application for the company I work for. We handle a lot of data and I'm looking for a way to reflect changes made by other users as fast as possible. Ajax would be the solution, but the amount of data is so big that I'm afraid that if refresh the data in a short interval of time the network traffic would be a serious problem.

Is there any way of target a specific change or trigger some kind of event that tells me what to update instead of reloading the entire table? I'm currently using ASP.Net Web Forms(C#) with oracle and jQuery besides the regular bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **SignalR** to send pings to all active users when ever there is any change in your data. You can call a Jquery method from your c# signalR code block, So with this just call specific methods which will update specific sections in the UI with Ajax calls.

[This example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526876/AddingplusSignalRplustoplusanplusASP-NetplusWebFor) should give you a basic understanding of how to get SignalR setup with WebForm. You have to write a ajax call inside the `logMessage` method and update only required part of the UI.